# Setting limits for the different shades in an Excel surface plot

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to set the colours for a surface plot. I would like to show them in three distinct groups - good, neutral and bad (green, amber and red).

These limits (currently 1bn, 2bn etc) are automatic but I would like to find a way to set these myself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am unclear why this is tagged also as excel-vba. It is also unclear if you put effort into finding out how to do this. Always do a good google before asking.

Excel problem 1: You don't know how to set these ranges manually.
Excel answer  1: You select the vertical (Value) axis, right click, format axis, and change the min, max, and major unit. The coloration is taken from here.

Excel problem 2: You want to change what the values are called in the legend.
Excel answer  2: Not sure you can actually do this.

Excel problem 3: You want to do this programmatically.
Excel answer  3: Assuming the chart is selected.

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = MyMaximumValue
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MyMinimumValue
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = MyDivisionValue
```

Comment: To respond to your points here: 1) yes I did try Google thank you; 2) I was looking to modify what the coloured groups were (shown in the legend), not the axis values; 3) I had thought you may need to use VBA to make these changes. So to conclude these don't really help, I'm looking to see if I can set the groups that the legend shows manually.